# Is it possible to use method chaining assigning strings in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, variable-assignment, method-chaining

I want to use method chaining syntax using JavaScript and AngularJS. I assign arrays and strings.

This code works:

```
$mdDateLocaleProvider
     .shortDays = ['Do', 'Lu', 'Ma', 'Mi', 'Ju', 'Vi', 'Sá']
     .msgCalendar = 'Calendario'
;
```

This code doesn't work:

```
$mdDateLocaleProvider
     .shortDays = ['Do', 'Lu', 'Ma', 'Mi', 'Ju', 'Vi', 'Sá']
     .msgCalendar = 'Calendario'
     .msgOpenCalendar = 'Abrir calendario'
;
```

I think the **msgOpenCalendar = 'Abrir calendario'** sentence is failing due to the string assignment.

My solution:

```
$mdDateLocaleProvider
     .shortDays = ['Do', 'Lu', 'Ma', 'Mi', 'Ju', 'Vi', 'Sá']
     .msgCalendar = 'Calendario'
;
$mdDateLocaleProvider
     .msgOpenCalendar = 'Abrir calendario'
;
```

Why is there a problem assigning a string but isn't with an array?

Comment: *"This code works"* – not as you might think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name is **method** chaining for a reason, it is used to chain **methods**, not variable assignments.

In method chaining, you are simply returning the object instance (of a mutable or a new immutable object) in the end of the method (function), so you can call the next function "right away".

The reason it "works" is that an array in JS is an object, so you simply placed a `msgCalendar` property on the array that you assigned to `shortDays` property.

Basically, what you achieved is:

```
var shortDays = ['Do', 'Lu', 'Ma', 'Mi', 'Ju', 'Vi', 'Sá'].msgCalendar = 'Calendario';
// here shortDays actually equals to 'Calendario', because it is like writing a = b = 2.
$mdDateLocaleProvider.shortDays = shortDays;
$mdDateLocaleProvider.msgOpenCalendar = 'Abrir calendario';
```

Comment: I believe what he *actually* achieved was `$mdDLP.shortDays = 'Calendario'`, with the array getting lost in the process.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use method chaining with direct assignments like you're doing. As explained by Ron, what you think it does is not what it's actually doing.

A way of working around this is implementing the [Builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern#Java) that would allow you to create objects based on chaining their setters methods.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use chaining, but as you included the angularjs tag in the question, you probably want to look at using `angular.extend`:

```
angular.extend($mdDateLocaleProvider, {
     shortDays: ['Do', 'Lu', 'Ma', 'Mi', 'Ju', 'Vi', 'Sá'],
     msgCalendar: 'Calendario',
     msgOpenCalendar: 'Abrir calendario'
});
```

which will have the desired effect of updating the three properties and you can even use method chaining on the result if you want to call any methods.

Answer (score 0):

You want [`assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

```js
 Object.assign($mdDateLocaleProvider, {
      shortDays : ['Do', 'Lu', 'Ma', 'Mi', 'Ju', 'Vi', 'Sá']
      msgCalendar : 'Calendario'
      msgOpenCalendar : 'Abrir calendario'
 });
```

Which will set everything at once for you.

---

If you need to actually chain say like maybe set `shortDays`, call a function, then set `msgCalendar`, try my shim.
This will also work for when `assign` doesnt work (setting DOM `onclick`s or `innerText`s), or you need to call a function that doesn't chain.

```js
 wrap($mdDateLocaleProvider)
      .set('shortDays'      , ['Do', 'Lu', 'Ma', 'Mi', 'Ju', 'Vi', 'Sá'])
      .set('msgCalendar'    , 'Calendario')
      .set('msgOpenCalendar', 'Abrir calendario')
 ;
```

Simply call `wrap()` and away you go.

```js
wrap = (obj) => (Object.defineProperty(obj,
            'define', {value:(name, options) => (Object.defineProperty(obj, name, options))})
    .define('assign', {value:(props)         => (Object.assign(obj, props))                })
    .define('set'   , {value:(name, value)   => { obj[name] = value; return obj; }         })
    .define('invoke', {value:(name, ...args) => { obj[name](...args); return obj; }        })
);
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0L1v5sek/1/)

```js
let bob = {
    hello  : 'there',
    chains : () => {bob.I_RAN = true; return bob;},
    doesnt : (arg1, arg2) => {bob.I_RAN_ALSO = [arg1, arg2]; return null;}
};
wrap(bob)
    .set('oh', 'my')
    .chains()
    .invoke('doesnt', 'works', 'anyway')
    .assign({more:7, stuff:null})
;
for (let item of Object.keys(bob))
      console.log(`'${item}' : ${bob[item]}`);
```

Output:
[image]